# Adding elements to grid cell, Ext style

Tags: extjs

I have a grid in which I am adding active dom content into each cell. As of now, I am adding it as html text inside the column renderer:

```
renderer:function(data) {
    str = "";
    Ext.each(data,function(paragraph,i) {
        str += '<div onclick="Ext.getCmp(\'grid\').paragraphClick('+paragraph.get("Id")+');">'+paragraph.get("Text")+'</div>'
    });
    return str;
}
```

I should mention that `data` is a record field which contains another list of records.
Now, I guess you'll call this the "worst ExtJS code you have ever seen". That's fair.

But how would I do this in an ExtJS-conforming way, using Ext elements and listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cellclick event, then check the target:

```
renderer: function(v) {
     return '<div class="foo">' + v + '</div>';
}

listeners: {
    cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
        if (e.getTarget('.foo') {
            // clicked on foo, use record data to give you context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I did not yet find a similar solution for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events (like an Ext.Tooltip that is shown when the div is hovered).